# Stars with same colour

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astrophysics, sun, stars, luminosity

This is the problem I'm trying to solve.

> [image]

When it says they have the same colour, does that mean that they have the same temperature?

Comment: I believe so.  Temperature, and all that implies.

Comment: It is the same color, so the same temperature, so the same power per unit area

Comment: Well, there is a color temperature, blackbody temperature, and actual temperature but I am guessing based on the phrasing that yes, they assume the same temperature if the star has the same color.

Answer (score 1):

The observed colour of a star is representative of its photospheric effective temperature.

The caveats to this statement are that the calibration between observed colour and temperature is also gravity and composition dependent; and it also assumes that the observed colour has not been "reddened" by the effects of scattering by dust in the interstellar medium (or has been corrected for that).

So, to your question. You are told this star is 200pc away (from the Parallax), yet it is very bright; much brighter than the Sun would be at the same distance. The reddening by the ISM would be small out to a distance of 200pc in *most* directions, so you are invited to ignore that. In which case, you need to assume that this star has a solar composition and that the similar colours mean similar temperatures.

From there, this is a simple problem, but note that you will deduce that this star is much bigger than the Sun and so would likely have a much lower gravity. And as I said, the relationship between colour and temperature *is* somewhat gravity sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

i think so because so far what we have seen is that the color of the star can determine the temperature (like red stars are less hotter than the blue stars) so it is possible that the same color corresponds to same temperature.

and thanks for the correction

Comment: Blue stars are hotter than red stars.

Answer (score -1):

The other answers to this question are correct, but incomplete. It is the combined information that the star has the same colour as the sun, and the fact that the parallax angle tells us that the star is relatively nearby, that allows us to say the stars are at the same temperature.

If the star was very far away, the redshift of it's spectrum would become important.

Comment: The color doesn't depend on distance.